# Method for combined Periodic functions

Tags: applications, periodic-functions

I have this last question for my maths assignment and I'm stuck.
Consider the function: y=sin(px)+sin(qx) where ‘p’ and ’q’ are positive integers. In many cases, the sum of 2 periodic functions are also in nature ‘periodic’ and hence, devise a method for calculating the period of such functions if the values of ‘p’ and ‘q’ are known. Use at least 2 sets of data to substantiate your findings and comment on any strengths and limitations of your method.

I have been told that I don't have to have an equation, just a method, to create a new function. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is number theory. What if $p=2$ and $q=6$. Can you see that the period is $\pi=2\pi\div 2$? If $p=3$ and $q=9$, can you see that the period is $2\pi\div 3$? If $p=6$ and $q=8$, can you see that the period is $2\pi\div2$?

Comment: So, how did you get the numbers that were divided by 2pi?

Comment: I think that if I tell you “greatest common divisor”, I will have given the whole thing away. So I won’t say that.